# get category products by category id in opencart

Tags: opencart

hi i want to customize the feature module that as category is set through admin display the relevant product instead of featured module

when ever i select the category it displays category products what will be the code of controller which get category n give products array to that category

below is the view code of category select input

```
        <td><select name="category_id">

        <?php foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
         <?php } ?>

        </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductCategories(
    $this->request->get['product_id']);
foreach($categories as $category_id) {
   // do something
}
```

Add the `getProductCategories` function into `model/catalog/product.php`

```
public function getProductCategories($product_id) {
    $product_category_data = array();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX .
           "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $product_category_data[] = $result['category_id'];
    }
    return $product_category_data;
}
```